# Rapid react state object updating

Tags: reactjs

Let me describe the my goal at first. I have a custom hook named useForm. In this hook I handle my values and errors and warnings. Assume that my form element is like this:

```
const [values, setValues, errors, setError, warnings, setWarning] = useForm(initValues)

Section1
----<ComponentOfSection1 values onError />
----<ErrorsComponentOfSection1 errors />
Section2
----<ComponentOfSection2 values onError />
----<ErrorsComponentOfSection2 errors />
Section3
----<ComponentOfSection3 values onError />
----<ErrorsComponentOfSection3 errors />
```

Now, if any change applies to one of them, other will check the new value in their `useEffect` and if there i a problem for their component, will arise an error to update error list. like this:

In component 1:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let errors = [];
    errors.push({
      i18n: "defaultLangCannotBeUnselected",
      isExist: isDefaultLangUnselected(),
    });
    errors.push({
      i18n: "DefaultLangShouldBeInAvailableLangs",
      isExist: isDefaultLanguageIsNotInAvailable(),
    });
    props.onError(errors);  
  }, [translationMode]);
```

In component 2:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let errors = [], warnings = [];
    warnings.push({ i18n: "deepLKeyIsNotAValidKey", isExist: !isValidKey })
    errors.push({ i18n: "validDeepLKeyRequiredInstantMode", isExist: !isValidKey && translationMode == TRANSLATION_MODE.INSTANT_TRANSLATION_MODE })
    
    props.onError(errors);
    props.onWarning(warnings);

  }, [translationMode]);
```

As you can see by changing **translationMode**, two state updating for error state will be rise.  The first one always act as a normal updating and even its `useEffect` is called before second one starting to update and we have a new state as I can see in the console. But the problem is that when second updater comes, I have my old state in the starting point not the new one! So it update state on a wrong state. I  tried to use a queue. But the result is same.

****UPDATE****

My hook without queue:

```
const useForm = (initialValues) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

  const setError = (newState) => {
    let tempState = { ...errors };
    newState.forEach((_state) => {
      if (_state.isExist) {
        if (_state.i18n) tempState[_state.i18n] = _state.data;
      } else {
        if (tempState.hasOwnProperty(_state.i18n))
          delete tempState[_state.i18n];
      }
    });
    setErrors(tempState);
  };

  const setValue = (newState) => {
    let newVal = {};
    if (newState?.target?.name)
      newVal[newState.target.name] = newState.target.value;
    else newVal = { ...newState };
    setValues({ ...getState(), ...newState });
  };

  return [values, setValue, errors, setError];
};
export default useForm;
```

My hook with queue is like this:

```
var valueQueue = [[]];
var errorQueue = [[]];
var warningsQueue = [[]];

const useForm = (initialValues) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);
  const [warnings, setWarnings] = useState([]);

  const [setValue, setNextValue] = getStateQueue(
    () => values,
    setValues,
    () => valueQueue,
    valueUpdater
  );
  const [setError, setNextError] = getStateQueue(
    () => errors,
    setErrors,
    () => errorQueue,
    errorUpdater
  );
  const [setWarning, setNextWarning] = getStateQueue(
    () => warnings,
    setWarnings,
    () => warningsQueue,
    errorUpdater
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setNextValue();
  }, [values]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      "ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRROR USEEFFECT",
      errors,
      new Date().getSeconds() + ":" + new Date().getMilliseconds()
    );
    setNextError();
  }, [errors]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setNextWarning();
  }, [warnings]);

  return [values, setValue, errors, setError, warnings, setWarning];
};

export default useForm;

const getStateQueue = (getState, stateSetter, getStateQueue, updateState) => {
  //STARTING POINT
  const setState = (newState) => {
    let queue = getStateQueue();
    if (queue == errorQueue)
      console.log(
        "ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRROR Setter 1",
        getState(),
        newState,
        getStateQueue()
      );
    queue.push(newState);
    if (queue.length == 1) {
      if (queue == errorQueue)
        console.log(
          "ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRROR Setter 2",
          getState(),
          newState,
          getStateQueue
        );
      updateState(getState, newState, stateSetter);
    }
  };

  const setNextState =  () => {
    let queue = getStateQueue();
    if (queue == errorQueue)
    console.log(
      "ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRROR Set Next 1",
      getState(),      
      getStateQueue()
    );
    queue.shift();
    if (queue.length > 0) {
      let reducer = (previousState, currentState) => ({
        ...previousState,
        ...currentState,
      });
      if (queue[0].constructor === Array)
        reducer = (previousState, currentState) => [
          ...previousState,
          ...currentState,
        ];
      let newState = queue.reduce(reducer);
      queue = [newState];
      updateState(getState, newState, stateSetter);
    }
    if (queue == errorQueue)
    console.log(
      "ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRROR Set Next 2",
      getState(),      
      getStateQueue()
    );
  };

  return [setState, setNextState];
};

const errorUpdater =  (getState, newState, setter) => {
  let tempState = { ...getState() };
  console.log(
    "ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRROR UPDATER 1",
    getState(),
    newState
  );
  newState.forEach((_state) => {
    if (_state.isExist) {
      if (_state.i18n) tempState[_state.i18n] = _state.data;
    } else {
      if (tempState.hasOwnProperty(_state.i18n)) delete tempState[_state.i18n];
    }
  });
  console.log(
    "ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRROR UPDATER 2",
    getState(),
    newState
  );
  setter(tempState);
};

const valueUpdater =  (getState, newState, setter) => {
  let newVal = {};
  if (newState?.target?.name)
    newVal[newState.target.name] = newState.target.value;
  else newVal = { ...newState };
  setter({ ...getState(), ...newState, date: Date.now() });
};
```

and the console log:

[image]

Note: when I use a setTimeout in the one of validator to rise onError after 5 millisecond, it works fine!

Can you please help me with my mistake or any solution for it?

****UPDATE****

This code fixed my problem. I use the simple hook(without queue) and my setter is like this now:

```
const setError = (newState) => {
    setErrors((errors) => {
      let tempState = { ...errors };
      newState.forEach((_state) => {
        if (_state.isExist) {
          if (_state.i18n) tempState[_state.i18n] = _state.data;
        } else {
          if (tempState.hasOwnProperty(_state.i18n))
            delete tempState[_state.i18n];
        }
      });
      return tempState;
    });
  };
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `getStateQueue` and the other utilities? Your code seems very convoluted for just enqueueing state updates.

Comment: @DrewReese getStateQueue  is for creating queue and manage the updating if the state is object or array for values, errors and warnings. You can ignore this queue. Because I implement it just for fixing this problem. With queue and without it, in the rapid updating I have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if we can ignore the `getStateQueue` and related utilities, then my original suspicion is what I think is the issue. You are enqueueing multiple state updates within a render cycle and the previous updates are overwritten.

Use a functional state update to correctly update from the previous state (***not the state from the previous render cycle!!***).

Example:

Given that `errors` state is an array, and is being updated with an array of errors.

```
setErrors(errors => [...errors, ...newErrors]);
```

Note that I suspect there is likely a case where you want to clear the errors, such as when revalidating the form.

```
setErrors([]);
```